# FrameLayout overflows Window in CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-framelayout

I wanted to implement `FrameLayout` with `toolbar` for `scrolling_view_behaviour`.
But when I set `layout_height` of `FrameLayout` to `match_parent`, it overflows as shown in the picture below:

[image]

this is my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.NewsActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        >

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:titleTextColor="#fff" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"


        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_insetEdge="start">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/navHostFragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"

            app:navGraph="@navigation/news_nav_graph" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#fff"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"
        app:layout_insetEdge="bottom"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I am sorry if this question is repeated or silly, I couldn't find anything which could solve my problem. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove attributes which refer to `ConstraintLayout` because you are not using one here. Also the `FrameLayout`. Adding margin to bottom of `Fragment` will set it in proper way.

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:titleTextColor="#fff" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navHostFragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="112dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/news_nav_graph"
        tools:ignore="FragmentTagUsage" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#fff"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

As you can see i have added

```
android:layout_marginBottom="112dp"
```

But if you add `56dp` to it, it will put bottom 56dp layout behind `BottomNavigationView`. To avoid that inside child fragments which are in other layouts just add more 56dp to it.